# iOS 11 No background color for status bar in master side of splitview

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ios11

I have seen a couple of issues similar to this but theirs seemed to be in the main view of their app. I have tried some of their suggestions like deselecting "Safe Area Relieve Margins" in the Size Inspector pane but none have worked.  In the Detail side of my iPad app, the background color of my navigation bar stops at the status bar.

[image]

In this screenshot, I tried to use MMDrawerController to see if using something other than UISplitViewController would work but I have the same problem for both. So far the only difference between the two libraries is I haven't seen UISplitViewController work at all but with MMDrawerController, if you set openDrawerGestureModeMask to MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView and the master view stretches a little bit then the background color renders correctly.

I saw on one of the other post that their issue was a bug for Xcode and there had been several people who already filed their bug Apple. Could this be a separate issue that Apple needs to know about as well if it is a iOS bug?

This is not an issue for iOS 9.X or 10.X, only 11.X.

Comment: Can you confirm if status bar background is transparent on Drawer controller? and is this still an issue ?

Comment: Yes, the status bar background is transparent. I've since had to move on to other projects but I just went back to it and looked and it seems to be working properly now.

Comment: Any idea why this was resolved for you? Experiencing this on iPad with SplitViewController in iOS 11.4.1

Comment: Sorry, no, not specifically. I use MMDrawerController and haven't seen this issue again.